# Unable to understand the function of app.use('/') in express framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Here is my code -

```
//declared express, body-parser, mongodb, http, cors.

 var app = express();

 app.use(cors());

 app.use(express.urlencoded());

   // Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
  app.use(express.json());

   var CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
   var DATABASE_NAME = "real_india_db0";
   var database = "real_india_db0";
   var collection = "db0"

    app.listen(3000, () => {
      MongoClient.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (error, client) => {
     if(error) {
        throw error;
    }
    database = client.db(DATABASE_NAME);
    collection = database.collection("db0");
    console.log("Connected to `" + DATABASE_NAME + "`!");
    });

 });

 app.post("/enterTasks", (request, response) => {

 var requestBody = [

    { 'taskId': 1,   'projectId' : 1,  'content' : {'name': 'Task 1' , 'predecessors':[], 
  'successor':  [{2}]  } ]
  console.log("abc ....", requestBody);

 });
```

After running -

```
  node app.js
```

I am hitting this particular url -

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8081/enterTasks
```

But the console.log is not getting print in the developer console -->

```
  console.log("abc ....", requestBody)
```

I wish to know why is this particular error taking place.

Comment: are you saying when you do this `console.log("abc ....", requestBody)`, it won't show your results in the web console?

Comment: Hi Gianluca, yess

Comment: that is because when you log something in the server side code (in your nodejs files) it will always log to your server side console (terminal), where if you log something from your html, ejs, etc files, it will log to the web console

Comment: ok. Will do !! Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/enterTasks", (request, response) => {

 var requestBody = [

    { 'taskId': 1,   'projectId' : 1,  'content' : {'name': 'Task 1' , 'predecessors':[], 
  'successor':  [{2}]  } ]
  console.log("abc ....", requestBody);

 });
```

This is in a post request, if your requesting this in a browser change:

```
app.post()
```

To

```
app.get()
```

Comment: ok. I will try this . thanks for your reply